# Cypress V10. Not Reading data in BDD test: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mobileHandset')

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, fixtures, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I hope someone can help, I've just converted a Cypress Mocha framework to BDD.  Before converting it was running perfectly and the test was running smoothly.  Now I've converted it I seem to be getting an error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mobileHandset')`.  I never had this issue before so I'm very confused. here is the code [and watch this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb03uoydh2yf3ij/Stackoverflow.mov?dl=0)

Feature:

```
Feature: End to End Shopping Purchase Validation

 Registered user will be able to purchase an item and have it shipped to their country

    Scenario: Customer Purchase and delivery
    
    Given  I am on the eCommerce page
    When I add items to cart 
    And I confirm shopping cart total
    Then I select my delivery country and see a thank for your order notification
```

Step Definition

```
import { Given, And, Then, When } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import Homepage from '../../../support/pageObjects/Homepage'
import orderSummaryPage from '../../../support/pageObjects/orderSummaryPage'
import completeOrderPage from '../../../support/pageObjects/completeOrderPage'
const data = require ('../../../fixtures/example.json');

const homepage = new Homepage()
const StartCheckout = new orderSummaryPage()
const CompleteOrder = new completeOrderPage()



Given(/^I am on the eCommerce page$/, () => {
    cy.visit(``+"/angularpractice/")

});

When(/^I add items to cart$/, function() {
    
  homepage.getShopTab().click({force:true}) 

    this.data.mobileHandset.forEach(function(element) {// this custom commad will add items to your cart

          cy.AddToCart(element)  
        }); 

        StartCheckout.getBasketCheckoutButton().click()

});

When(/^I confirm shopping cart total$/, () => {

    let sum=0
   
    CompleteOrder.getProductCost().each(($e1, index, $list) =>{

      const unitCost=$e1.text()  
      let res= unitCost.split(" ") 
      res= res[1].trim() 
      sum=Number(sum)+Number(res)
      
  }).then(function() 
  {
      cy.log(sum)
  
  })
});

Then(/^I select my delivery country and see a thank for your order notification$/, () => {
    
    StartCheckout.getStartCheckoutButton().click()
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountry().type('United Kingdom')
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountryConfirm().click()
    CompleteOrder.getTermsConditionsCheckbox().click({force: true})
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseButton().click()
    
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseAlert().then(function(element){

      
       const actualText= element.text()
      expect(actualText.includes('Success')).to.be.true
   
     }) 
    
});
```

Here is the data

```
{
  "name": "MY_NAME",
  "gender": "Female",
  "mobileHandset": ["Blackberry", "Nokia Edge"]
  
  
}
```

BeforeEach

```
beforeEach(function()
{

    cy.fixture('example').then(function(data){ 
 
        this.data=data 

       })

})
```

After discussion I moved the BeforeEach file to Support. Still getting the original error

[image]

Comment: Use the arrow function syntax for the cypress fixture callback. You want to set data property on the `thisArg`  of the beforeEach callback. Also, I recommend using `BeforeEach` hook from `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Comment: I get it so use => instead of function.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, use the arrow-function-syntax in the then callback of the cypress fixture

Comment: I just added those changes  and got the following  still not allowing me to access the data https://www.dropbox.com/s/uekrda7chbx8k5m/BeforeEach.mov?dl=0

Comment: I dont think that the `beforeEach` module is being autorun by cypress. 
You need to import it explicitly in the tests that way.
If you want it to be autorun by Cypress,  move the code in that module to `cypress/support/index.js`.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule. That didn't work.  Still got the same result.

Comment: Add a console.log in the beforeEach hook to debug it and verify that it gets called. Try and rename the `beforeEach.js` file to `index.js`. You can read on [configuring the support file for Cypress tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)

Comment: It worked.  also modified in the step definition the new location  to support for before each to `const data = require ('../../../support/beforeEach');` @OluwafemiSule thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import the data fixture if you already have it in the [cypress/fixtures folder](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Usage).

You can load the fixture in the Before hook before your tests.

```js
import { 
    Given,
    And,
    Then,
    When,
    Before 
} from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
//...

Before(function() {
    cy.fixture('example').then((data) => {
        this.data = data;
    });
});
//...
```

Comment: I already have this in my code.  Let me post it.  I don't think it made much difference

Comment: Not all of the above. Make just the changes necessary to load the fixture in your Before hook.

Comment: I will add to my question  what i have in the before Each hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `beforeEach()` should be working, but it's not necessary you can just refer to `data` instead of `this.data`.

```js
const data = require ('../../../fixtures/example.json');  // data available anywhere in this step
...
When(/^I add items to cart$/, () => {
  ...
  data.mobileHandset.forEach(element => {
    cy.AddToCart(element)  
  })
  ...
})
```

---

The convention is to use `cy.fixture()`

```js
When(/^I add items to cart$/, () => {
  ...
  cy.fixture('example.json').then(data => {    // no ../.. needed
    data.mobileHandset.forEach(element => {
      cy.AddToCart(element)  
    })
  }) 
  ...
});
```